# Groovy-wslite:SOAP Client Exception Handshake Failure

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to invoke a SOAP service using Groovy wslite. But I keep error indicating PKIX path building failed.

```
import wslite.soap.*
import wslite.http.*

def client = new SOAPClient("endpointURL")
client.httpClient.sslTrustStoreFile = "path to key.jks"
client.httpClient.sslTrustStorePassword ="password"
client.httpClient.sslTrustAllCerts = true

def response = client.send(request)
```

I am running the code as groovy script from SoapUI client. I am able to invoke the same service from SoapUI with same jks file without any issues.

Could some help me understand what is that I am missing?

Stacktrace

```
Sun Jan 17 23:46:01 PST 2016:ERROR:wslite.soap.SOAPClientException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
   wslite.soap.SOAPClientException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:202)
    at wslite.soap.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.groovy:64)
    at wslite.soap.SOAPClient$send$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at wslite.soap.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.groovy:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at wslite.soap.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.groovy)
    at wslite.soap.SOAPClient$send.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script3.run(Script3.groovy:10)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:92)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:141)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at wslite.http.HTTPClient.buildResponse(HTTPClient.groovy:152)
    at wslite.http.HTTPClient.this$2$buildResponse(HTTPClient.groovy)
    at wslite.http.HTTPClient$this$2$buildResponse.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at wslite.http.HTTPClient.execute(HTTPClient.groovy:60)
    at wslite.http.HTTPClient$execute.call(Unknown Source)
    at wslite.soap.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.groovy:60)
    ... 18 more
   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentEncoding(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentEncoding(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at wslite.http.HTTPClient.buildResponse(HTTPClient.groovy:151)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: **PKIX path building** means, that your client is trying to find issuers certificates for the server until it finds trusted CA certificate, and this fails. I would guess, you have not all the cerificates in your `path to key.jks`. Double check if you are using the same file as SoapUI. Also you should post the whole **error stack**.

Comment: I have only one certificate and I have verified using keytool that the certificate is present in the jks file. Stack Trace is added now to the original question. Also I was getting the PKIX error when the line "client.httpClient.sslTrustAllCerts = true" was set as false.

Comment: You mean, the server uses only one **selfsigned certificate**? You should double check that. Now, `handshake_failure` looks like your **server** is requesting **client authentication**, which is a different error with different solution. You can log the communication with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`

Answer (score 0):

Though it's a bit outdated, I'll try to answer your question.
If you are passing your path to key.jks and password as variables, not as plain text, the problem may be there.
I had more or less same issue, when I was able to send request and get 200 response code via SoapUI, but my SOAPClient couldn't do the same.
So I checked all variables in my header and found out that the header values which were supposed to be filled with values from variables were simply empty. I.e.:

```
    String type = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    ...
    Content-Type: type
```

So I replaced variables with plain text

```
Content-Type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

Suggest you do the same