# wslite soap connection reset, soapui is working with the same soap envelop

Tags: grails, soap, groovy, soapui, soap-client

The updated SOAP message in groovy-wslite (dev mode in GGTS) gives a connection reset message, and using the same message with SOAPUI 5.5.0 is working. Background info: Our database recently moved from on the premises to online, the provider changed from http to https, usage of a token, and from http to https, we are using Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14) and grails 2.3.11.

I have tried using different syntax as shown in https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite, but with no result. Others mentioned how to activate TLSv1.2 in Java 7.

```
    getconnectorurl = 'https://123456.soap.afas.online/profitservices/appconnectorget.asmx'
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
    String soapRequest = """
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Afas.Profit.Services">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <urn:GetData>
            <urn:token><![CDATA[<token><version>1</version><data>${tokenString}</data></token>]]></urn:token>
            <urn:connectorId>${function}</urn:connectorId>
            <urn:filtersXml/>
            <urn:skip>0</urn:skip>
            <urn:take>20</urn:take>
        </urn:GetData>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>"""
    log.info("soapRequest=${soapRequest}");

    try {
//          SOAPResponse response = client.send(SOAPAction: "urn:Afas.Profit.Services", SOAPVersion.V1_1, connectTimeout:7000, readTimeout:9000,useCaches:false, followRedirects:true, sslTrustAllCerts:true,soapRequest);
//          SOAPResponse response = client.send(SOAPAction: 'urn:Afas.Profit.Services/GetData', soapRequest);
            SOAPResponse response = client.send(soapRequest);
```

SOAPUI returns the expected 20 records, wslite return a connection reset message, wireshark show Client Hello, followed by Server Hello, etc, but wslite stops after Client Hello. The provider uses TLSv1.2. so I added the System.setProperty(...), and wireshark log shows TLSv1.2.

**grails log**
sce.message=Connection reset
2019-07-01 10:53:11,595 [INFO] grails.app.services.afas.AfasDataCollectorService - sce=wslite.soap.SOAPClientException: Connection reset
2019-07-01 10:53:11,597 [INFO] grails.app.services.afas.AfasDataCollectorService - sce.dump=https://123456.soap.afas.online/profitservices/appconnectorget.asmx headers={Content-Type=text/xml; charset=UTF-8} readTimeout=0 connectTimeout=0 method=POST> response=null detailMessage=Connection reset cause=java.net.SocketException: Connection reset stackTrace=[] suppressedExceptions=[]>

**SOAPUI log**
    Mon Jul 01 09:49:13 CEST 2019:DEBUG:>> "POST /profitservices/appconnectorget.asmx HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
    Mon Jul 01 09:49:13 CEST 2019:DEBUG:>> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
    Mon Jul 01 09:49:13 CEST 2019:DEBUG:>> "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
    Mon Jul 01 09:49:13 CEST 2019:DEBUG:>> "SOAPAction: "urn:Afas.Profit.Services/GetData"[\r][\n]"
    Mon Jul 01 09:49:13 CEST 2019:DEBUG:>> "Content-Length: 531[\r][\n]"
    Mon Jul 01 09:49:13 CEST 2019:DEBUG:>> "Host: 086312.soap.afas.online[\r][\n]"
    Mon Jul 01 09:49:13 CEST 2019:DEBUG:>> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
    Mon Jul 01 09:49:13 CEST 2019:DEBUG:>> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"

wireshark info:
[image]

[image]

Update: grails -Dgrails.full.stacktrace=true run-app in development mode, but app_stacktrace.log stays empty.

Update: added printStackTrace()

```
| Error wslite.soap.SOAPClientException: Connection reset
| Error     at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor145.newInstance(Unknown Source)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1002)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:202)
| Error     at wslite.soap.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.groovy:61)
| Error     at wslite.soap.SOAPClient$send$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
| Error     at wslite.soap.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.groovy:48)
| Error     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor359.invoke(Unknown Source)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1276)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
| Error     at wslite.soap.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.groovy)
| Error     at wslite.soap.SOAPClient$send.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
| Error     at afas.AfasDataCollectorService$$ERUyIxt2.getXMLData(AfasDataCollectorService.groovy:74)
| Error     at afas.AfasDataCollectorService$$DRUyIxt2.getXMLData(Unknown Source)
| Error     at afas.AfasDataCollectorService.getXMLData(AfasDataCollectorService.groovy)
| Error     at afas.AfasDataCollectorService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c886fe00.invoke(<generated>)
| Error     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
| Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:700)
| Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
| Error     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
| Error     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
| Error     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
| Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
| Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:633)
| Error     at afas.AfasDataCollectorService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c01f8292.getXMLData(<generated>)
| Error     at afas.AfasDataCollectorService$getXMLData.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at afas.AfasDataCollectorService$getXMLData.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at afas.EmployeeService.runImport(EmployeeService.groovy:22)
| Error     at afas.EmployeeService$runImport.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at afas.ImportAfasEmployeesJob.execute(ImportAfasEmployeesJob.groovy:20)
| Error     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor358.invoke(Unknown Source)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.invoke(OriginalClassInvoker.java:47)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1299)
| Error     at grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:104)
| Error     at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
| Error     at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
| Error Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
| Error     at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor133.newInstance(Unknown Source)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
| Error     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
| Error     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1673)
| Error     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1671)
| Error     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1244)
| Error     at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
| Error     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
| Error     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor375.invoke(Unknown Source)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1276)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1725)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1140)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3461)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1152)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.callGetProperty(PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:41)
| Error     at wslite.http.HTTPClient.buildResponse(HTTPClient.groovy:152)
| Error     at wslite.http.HTTPClient.this$2$buildResponse(HTTPClient.groovy)
| Error     at wslite.http.HTTPClient$this$2$buildResponse$8.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
| Error     at wslite.http.HTTPClient.execute(HTTPClient.groovy:60)
| Error     at wslite.http.HTTPClient$execute.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at wslite.soap.SOAPClient.send(SOAPClient.groovy:57)
| Error     ... 41 more
| Error Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
| Error     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
| Error     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
| Error     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
| Error     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
| Error     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
| Error     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
| Error     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
| Error     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
| Error     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
| Error     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
| Error     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
| Error     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2678)
| Error     at java.net.URLConnection.getContentEncoding(URLConnection.java:533)
| Error     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentEncoding(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:410)
| Error     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor373.invoke(Unknown Source)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1276)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1725)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1140)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3461)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1152)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:174)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.callGetProperty(PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:41)
| Error     at wslite.http.HTTPClient.buildResponse(HTTPClient.groovy:151)
| Error     ... 46 more
```

Comment: please show full error with stacktrace. this will help to understand your problem.

Comment: maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847177/groovy-wslitesoap-client-exception-handshake-failure ?

Comment: I added the requested stacktrace information, please have a look, thanks in advance.